# Why my array in vue does't affect page data is updated?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I am writing simple application in vue where i am requesting server for data. Data are recieved and wrriten to two array of object but they are not updated to my html.

I had to change delimeters because i use django. I check the data (if its really there) and tried some dummy data to try if the vue app works and every thinks seems fine.

Vue app:

```
var app1 = new Vue({
    delimiters :['[[', ']]'],
    el: "#app-1",
    data:{
        questions : [{text:"test", 'pk':1}],
        possible : [{text:"test", 'pk':1}]
    },
    created:()=>{
        let  pk = $("#pk").val()
        SetupCSRF();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"/tester/test/questions",
            data:JSON.stringify({pk:pk}),
            contentType:"application/json",
            dataType:"json",
            success:(data)=>{
                console.log(data);
                this.questions = data.questions;
                this.possible = data.possible;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

part of html where i use vue:

```html
<div id="app-1">
    <div class="testquestions">
        <div v-for="question in questions">
            <div>[[question.text]]</div>
            <button class="remove" v-bind:value="question.pk">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="questions" v-for="p in possible">
            <p>[[p.text]]</p>
            <button class="add" v-bind:value="p.pk">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="test">click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: alteration:
<div>[[question.text]]</div>
to
<div>{{question.text}}</div>

Comment: i changed delimiters to [[]] because of template language of django and it works with dummy data, it's just doesn't update

Comment: To have reactivity with vue, you must have data interpolation.
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text

Comment: that's problem with django. It uses same style for writing data to template so i had to change by  setting delimiters : `delimiters :['[[', ']]']`

Comment: Is there a bug in the console?

Comment: Restrictions: This option is only available in the full build, with in-browser compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```js
created:()=>{
```

By using an arrow function you're losing your `this` context. It won't refer to the Vue instance, instead you'll be adding these properties to an unrelated object:

```js
this.questions = data.questions;
this.possible = data.possible;
```

Try console logging `this` to see what I mean.

You should just need to change it to a normal function, like this:

```js
created () {
```